# Explain the Code and why Subtract the substring

Tags: java

```
public boolean frontAgain(String str)
{
int len = str.length();
if(len >= 2)
    return str.substring(0, 2).equals(str.substring(len-2, len));
else
    return false;
}
```

Can someone please explain why the second substring statement using a word example and a step by step analysis. The program checks if first two letters match the last two letters.  for example the word was edited.

Comment: Max Zoom but what I am asking is that what does str.substring(len-2,len) does.

Comment: It returns the last two characters, because `len` (at this point) is the total number of characters in the string.

Comment: @lordzee Surely you've checked the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.substring(len-2, len)` asks for the last two letters of a string.

To get the last two letters, you need the beginning value of the substring to be the length (5) minus 2 characters, which gives you 3. This is because indexes in Java start at 0. For example, the positions for the characters in the string "horse" are 01234 (i.e. "h" is at index 0, "o" is at index 1 etc.), and the length is 5.

The second parameter of String.subString is for the ending index, which is *exclusive*. This means the first character position that is not part of the substring you want. In this case, it would be the length because that is 1 character higher than the end of the string.

If you put all that together, you get the following:

```
String str = "horse"
int length = str.length() // 5
String lastTwoChars = str.substring(length-2, length); // from position 3 to 5
System.out.println(lastTwoChars); // would show you "se"
```

The documentation for [String.substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).